How do I identify the file headers on .lzs files, and how exactly does lzss compression work?
I have some .lzs files from a mobile game that I am trying to decompress. I did research into the lzs compression algorithm, and I wrote a Java program for compressing and decompressing lzs compressed data. It was only after I wrote this program that I noticed that the data on the file that I was trying to decompress began with the byte F3 (11110011), and lzs compressed data cannot begin with a 1 bit. I actually referenced this issue in a previously asked question:
Can a .LZS file start with a 1 bit and still be considered LZS compressed?
After doing some further research, I learned that files with the .lzs extension often actually use lzss compression rather than lzs (the extension is just labelled as .lzs so that the extension can be 3 letters). As such, I took to researching lzss compression instead. At my current point in my research, I cannot yet tell whether or not my lzs files use lzss compression. Here are some of the files, so that you can get a look at them yourselves. You should be able to see the actual bytes and their corresponding ascii if you use a program like freefileviewer or any other hex viewer.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1CFI_QAIsyj0UrXfM5loeAdVbl_KNKYfj/view?usp=sharing
https://drive.google.com/file/d/10o1GhEtGX-zksdEEXwz_U_dceqlmVElC/view?usp=sharing
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Jp0o0veJHBb_CgxRHNpGtHMLqzIhPOEP/view?usp=sharing
Now, one of the first things that you may notice about all of these files is the fact that despite being mostly encoded, they all have the word BULLETS in plain English very early on in the file (preceded by the byte FF and followed by a 01 byte and an F7 byte). A slight distortion of the word "prologue" with a null byte and the letter f can also be seen on all of these files shortly afterwards.
Could any of these bytes indicate some sort of header? Can anyone look at these files and see if you can identify any file headers? Headers were referenced as a potential solution in the previous thread that I mentioned before. However, I'm still not quite clear when it comes to file headers.
Furthermore, I haven't really finished my studies of lzss compression. However, from what I have gathered, these files do not look lzss compressed. I do not see a single instance of a token like "<10,5>" on any of these files. Wouldn't tokens like these be present on files that are lzss compressed? Do you guys think that these files are lzss compressed?
My understanding of lzss compression thus far comes from these wiki pages:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lempel%E2%80%93Ziv%E2%80%93Storer%E2%80%93Szymanski#:~:text=Lempel%E2%80%93Ziv%E2%80%93Storer%E2%80%93Szymanski%20%28LZSS%29%20is%20a%20lossless%20data%20compression%20algorithm%2C,pp.%20928%E2%80%93951%29.%20LZSS%20is%20a%20dictionary%20coding%20technique.
https://go-compression.github.io/algorithms/lzss/
One last thing: The examples with Green Eggs and Ham in the wiki confuse me at certain parts.
  0: I am Sam
  9:
 10: Sam I am
 19:
 20: That Sam-I-am!
 35: That Sam-I-am!
 50: I do not like
 64: that Sam-I-am!
 79: 
 80: Do you like green eggs and ham?
112:
113: I do not like them, Sam-I-am.
143: I do not like green eggs and ham.

The above text gets compressed to:
 0: I am Sam
 9:
10: (5,3) (0,4)
16:
17: That(4,4)-I-am!(19,15)
32: I do not like
46: t(21,14)
50: Do you(58,5) green eggs and ham?
79: (49,14) them,(24,9).(112,15)(92,18).


Can someone explain this? Specifically, why does that (0,4) token have an offset of 0? How can any matching pattern have an offset of 0? Also, is that (4,4) token even accurate? That token replaces " Sam', but 4 characters prior to the space character is just the 'T' in "That". That doesn't seem like a match to me. That (21,14) token seems to give off a wrong offset too. The token is replacing "hat Sam-I-am!\n" (The newline characters are counted too). However, counting 21 characters backwards from the 'h' does not get you even close to the 'h' of the previous instance of "hat Sam-I-am!\n". Can someone please help me understand this lzss compression (as well as how this type of compression actually works when compressing files, because I don't see anything reminiscent of a token on my files)?
Thank you

Take a look at https://aluigi.altervista.org/quickbms.htm

LZ-whatever compressed data will never have things like "<10,5>" or "(24,9)". Those would be coded much more compactly as bit sequences.
